# Save self-generated Excel file as UploadedFile

Tags: python, django, excel

I have a huge string that contains CSV data. I want to convert it to an Excel file (.xslx) and save it as an `UploadedFile`/`SimpleUploadedFile`. I googled as best as I could and came up with the following. `result_data` being the huge string, obviously.

```
from io import StringIO

import pandas

from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile

### irrelevant code

result_data = StringIO(result_data)

df = pandas.DataFrame.from_csv(result_data, sep=';')
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

result_file = writer.book
result_data.seek(0)

mimetype = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'

object.xls_file = SimpleUploadedFile('filename.xlsx', result_data.read(), content_type=mimetype)
object.save()
```

I've tried numerous replacements for `result_data.read()` such as `result_data`, `result_file`, `result_file.read()`, but so far none of them has worked.

EDIT: I modified my code according to jmcnamara's suggestions, but got an error from `writer.save()`.

```
output = StringIO()
result_data = StringIO(result_data)

df = pandas.DataFrame.from_csv(result_data, sep=';')

writer = pandas.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/commands/create.py", line 67, in handle
    writer.save()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 1413, in save
    return self.book.close()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/xlsxwriter/workbook.py", line 296, in close
    self._store_workbook()
  File "/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/xlsxwriter/workbook.py", line 541, in _store_workbook
    xlsx_file.write(os_filename, xml_filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/zipfile.py", line 1373, in write
    self.fp.write(zinfo.FileHeader(zip64))
TypeError: string argument expected, got 'bytes'
Exception ignored in: <bound method ZipFile.__del__ of <zipfile.ZipFile object at 0x7fe5fa2077f0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/zipfile.py", line 1466, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/zipfile.py", line 1573, in close
    self.fp.write(endrec)
TypeError: string argument expected, got 'bytes'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to close/save the xlsx file created by pandas before trying to read the data:

```
writer.save()
```

Also, with Pandas 0.17+ you can use a StringIO/BytesIO object as a filehandle to pd.ExcelWriter. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import StringIO

output = StringIO.StringIO()

# Use the StringIO object as the filehandle.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter')

# Write the data frame to the StringIO object.
pd.DataFrame().to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
xlsx_data = output.getvalue()

# Do something with the data...
```

Comment: The error you get is due to a difference between Python 2 and Python 3. For Python 3 replace the StringIO parts with `import io` and `output = io.BytesIO()`.